# set kendo grid jquery command dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-grid, kendo-ui-grid

I have a simple grid just have two columns, the first column is name, second column is the command column. Is there a way to set the command column dynamic? For example, if the last name is "doe" then display both "edit" and "delete" button, otherwise, only display "edit" button.

```
<div id="grid"></div>
<script>
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [
    { field: "name" },
    { command: ["edit", "destroy"] } // displays the built-in "edit" and "destroy" commands
  ],
  editable: "inline",
  dataSource: {
    data: [ {Id: 1, name: "Jane Doe" }，{Id: 2, name: "Emily Doe" }, {Id: 3, name: "Emily White" }],
    schema: {
      model: {
        id: "Id",
        fields: {
          name: { type: "string" }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
</script>
```

Comment: Setting up a dojo or fiddle can help.  Here's your code : https://dojo.telerik.com/UZUCIBuf/2